# Dynamic Div Layout

Tags: css, html, layout

I know there are a lot of posts about div layouts but what I'm looking to do doesn't seem to be on here. I am creating div's that contain dynamic text. Therefore each div is of variable length. I want these div's placed alongside each other, 4 across the page. In other words, each div occupies 25% of the width. The number of div's is variable as well so if there are more than 4 div's, then the remaining would start be placed below in the same fashion. Below is a picture of what I am trying to depict, with the gray boxes being the div's I am creating. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

[image: Desired Layout]

The div's are created in my function addSuggestion(), which is as follows:

HTML:

```
addSuggestion = function (counter, company_name, contact_name, street_address_1, street_address_2, phone_number, email_address) {
    var output = document.getElementById('container');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var company = document.createElement('p');
    company.className = "companyClass";
    var contact = document.createElement('p');
    contact.className = "otherClass";
    var address1 = document.createElement('p');
    address1.className = "addressClass";
    var address2 = document.createElement('p');
    address2.className = "addressClass";
    var phone = document.createElement('p');
    phone.className = "otherClass";
    var email = document.createElement('p');
    email.className = "otherClass";

    if(counter%4 == 0) {
        div.className = "farleft";
    }
    else if(counter%4 == 1) {
        div.className = "centerleft";
    }
    else if(counter%4 == 2) {
        div.className = "centerright";
    }
    else {
        div.className = "farright";
    }

        if(company_name) {
        company.textContent = company_name;
        div.appendChild(company);
    }
    else {
        company.textContent = "*** COMPANY INFO ***";
        div.appendChild(company);
    }

    if(contact_name) {
        contact.textContent = contact_name;
        div.appendChild(contact);
    }

    if(street_address_1) {
            address1.textContent = street_address_1;
        div.appendChild(address1);
    }

    if(street_address_2) {
        address2.textContent = street_address_2;
        div.appendChild(address2);
    }

    if(phone_number) {
        phone.textContent = phone_number;
        div.appendChild(phone);
    }

        if(email_address) {
        email.textContent = email_address;
        div.appendChild(email);
    }

    output.appendChild(div);
}
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
#farleft {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
}
#centerleft {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
#centerright {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
}
#farright {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Your layout is definitely possible, what's the problem that you're having.

Comment: I create the div's in a function called addSuggestion(), which has a counter of the div's created, starting from zero. I used the modulus operator to determine which quadrant the div belongs in but I do not know how to define the quadrants or set the div to a quadrant

Comment: Please show some attempt at solving the problem prior to asking the question. In this case, some HTML and CSS code is required.

Comment: I have edited my post with my current implementation. As of now the div's align to the left, under each other.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `width: 25%` to each div will get your 4 divs on the same row (counting there are no borders and/or margin/padding on the exterior).

`float: left` will keep them to the left. In order to get your 'new row' to drop down a line, `<br clear="both">` would do the trick:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kanx/wzvqC/)

Comment: Using additional markup for the purpose of clearing is a poor practice.  There's no reason to specify a display type if you're just going to float it anyway (floating silently alters the element's display type).

Comment: On the back of your update, float them **all** to the left. Check my JSFiddle and let me know what you think.

Comment: Point taken, cimmanon. Left it in there when i was doing some testing and didn't think to remove it.

Comment: A new line needs to be called when ((counter % 4 == 0) && (counter != 0)). I created var newline = document.createElement('br') but I do not know what to do with var newline when that conditional is met

Comment: The padding is always on the interior. And also in this case it can be [`.farleft { clear:both; }`](http://jsfiddle.net/btcFj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If its a row of div's you can store them in a containing div "row" that has a variable height.

Sorry of that doesn't make much sense but try this CSS on the row's div.

```
min-height: 100px; /*whatever you want the minimum height to be*/
height:auto !important; /*An IE fix for older versions */
height:100%;
```

The above css will ensure your div is never smaller than 100px but can grow based on its content.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple:

```css
#container>div {
    width:25%;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    float:left;
}
#container>div.farleft {
    clear:both;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btcFj/3/)